# How to redistributes hours in monthly report into a table with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, html-table, xslt-1.0

I have an XML report with hourly values in a row. I'd like to redistribute those values this way:
 - One column per hour
 - One row per day

What would be the basis of an XSL that would redistribute those values?
Here is a snipet of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report >
    <Heading>
        <General_information>
            <Date Execution="2016-05-20 22:15:00+02:00" Begin="2012-04-01 00:00:00+02:00" End="2012-05-01 00:00:00+02:00" TimeOffset="+02:00" DST="-1"/>
            <Calculation_description>Monthly-hourly report</Calculation_description>
        </General_information>
    </Heading>
    <Results_list Repetition="3600" >
        <Label>Hour</Label>
        <Result_line Number="2" Epoch="1333234800" Date="2012-04-01 01:00:00+02:00">
            <Line_name>2012-04-01 01:00:00+02:00</Line_name>
            <Val> </Val>
        </Result_line>
    ...
        <Result_line Number="476" Epoch="1334941200" Date="2012-04-20 19:00:00+02:00">
            <Line_name>2012-04-20 19:00:00+02:00</Line_name>
            <Val >13.16</Val>
        </Result_line>
        <Result_line Number="477" Epoch="1334944800" Date="2012-04-20 20:00:00+02:00">
            <Line_name>2012-04-20 20:00:00+02:00</Line_name>
            <Val >15.93</Val>
        </Result_line>
    ...
        <Result_line Number="720" Epoch="1335819600" Date="2012-04-30 23:00:00+02:00">
            <Line_name>2012-04-30 23:00:00+02:00</Line_name>
            <Val>25.52</Val>
        </Result_line>
        <Result_line Number="721" Epoch="1335823200" Date="2012-05-01 00:00:00+02:00">
            <Line_name>2012-05-01 00:00:00+02:00</Line_name>
            <Val >38.52</Val>
        </Result_line>
    </Results_list>
</Report>
```

I was thinking on basing a solution either on the `Result_line/@Number` attribute modulus 24 or on a `Result_line/@Date` attribute substring. But I only master `for-each` loops that I suspect to be a bad solution.

Off course I would add Header and Dates columns at a later stage.

For the moment I know to use XSLT 1.0.

Thanks

Comment: Will there always be exactly one `Result_line` for each hour in the given range? And will each day have 24 hours? Apparently not, since your example begins at Number = 2.

Comment: one Result_line for each hour : yes, Number begins with 2 always (don't know why).

Comment: Always 24 hours a day, let's consider it's true (it may be from 23 to 25 hours on switching winter/summer time, but I will manage).

Comment: This is confusing: if a day starts at hour 2, what hour does it end on? Could you provide a fuller example of the input - one that has at least two full days?

Comment: `Number` always begins with 2. It is not the day's hour. but we can assume that it is hour+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table is regular, and each date starts on hour = 2  and has exactly 24 hours, listed in order, you could do something quite simple as:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Report">
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th/>
                <xsl:for-each select="Results_list/Result_line[position() &lt; 24]">
                    <th>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@Number"/>
                    </th>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <xsl:for-each select="Results_list/Result_line[@Number mod 24 = 2]">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@Date, ' ')"/>
                    </th>
                    <xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::Result_line[position() &lt; 23]">
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Val"/>
                        </td>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, this *will* fail if a date is allowed to have 23 or 25 hours.

---

Alternatively, you could group the lines by date, using [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html), and generate a cell for each line in the date's row:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="line-by-date" match="Result_line" use="substring-before(@Date, ' ')" />

<xsl:template match="/Report">
    <table border="1">
        <xsl:for-each select="Results_list/Result_line[count(. | key('line-by-date', substring-before(@Date, ' '))[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:variable name="date" select="substring-before(@Date, ' ')" />
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$date"/>
                    </th>                   
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('line-by-date', $date)">
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Val"/>
                        </td>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I did not include a table header here, because I don't know what it should show.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael!

I could manage based on both solutions.

Alexandre